How to disable the Safety Check in Google Dialogflow CX?
We are developing an AI chatbot for a children's toy store, but we've encountered an issue where the AI cannot respond to any questions related to "children." After checking the backend, we found that these unanswerable questions trigger a "Rejected_Safety_Check" error message.
The error message in the Dialogflow CX:

Question was rejected by safety check:

We believe that Google's Safety Check is causing this issue. It seems that any mention of terms related to children automatically gets flagged due to Google's Protecting Children policy, preventing the AI from responding. As of today, we haven't found a way to disable this Safety Check.
We have tried setting the command "disable safety check" in the prompt configuration, but it didn't work.
How to disable the Safety Check in Google Dialogflow CX?

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Attempting to circumvent safety measures sounds like something that Google wouldn't be happy about... Us random strangers on the internet might be able to help you with a hacky way around, but probably only Google's customer service can tell you whether you can disable this.
